# Salvar imagem no banco de dados e dar restore no banco de dados com PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, image

Qual é a melhor maneira para salvar imagem no banco de dados PostgreSQL?

Atualmente tenho uma OID para salvar, eu consigo utilizar normalmente, tanto para salvar e para recuperar, porém quando vou dar restore na minha base de dados, ocorre o seguinte erro

`pg_restore: [arquivador (bd)] Erro ao PROCESSAR TOC:
 pg_restore: [arquivador (bd)] Erro no registro do TOC 583; 1247 49153 DOMAIN lo 
 postgres
 pg_restore: [arquivador (bd)] could not execute query: ERROR:  type "lo" 
 already exists
    Comando foi: CREATE DOMAIN lo AS oid;`

Isso porque estou fazendo o `restore` pelo proprio `pgadmin 9.4`, e quando eu tento dar `restore` na minha aplicação `C#` também não funciona. Existe outra maneira de salvar a imagem no banco de dados ou alguma maneira de dar `restore` para que isso funcione?

Comment: eu uso colunas `bytea` e tanto o dump quanto restore, faço pelos executaveis do próprio postgresql, `pg_dump` e `psql`

Comment: Mas como funciona? quando você recupera a imagem ela volta em byte e então você converte ela para image? do jeito que eu estou fazendo quando recupera a imagem tenho que informa um caminho para onde ela tem que ir por exemplo c:\imagem\ ... você pode me mostrar como é feito com bytea? envie como resposta que eu aceito :)

Comment: Certo, vou colocar como faço, porém agora estou no celular, assim que possível coloco, vlw

Comment: Obrigado, e no caso a coluna da tabela no pg é a bytea?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo

Comment: Certo, estou no aguardo de sua resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme falei nos comentários, utilizo a coluna como `bytea` (byte array) que pode armazenar não somente imagens, mas também arquivos de qualquer formato.

Segue o código conforme eu utilizo, porém este que coloco é apenas um exemplo utilizando a biblioteca `System.Data.ODBC` do .NET. Foi descartado outros trechos irrelevantes para a situação, focando apenas na seleção, inserção e atualização da coluna em `bytea`. Caso utilize outro método para conexão com o banco, é bem similar e acredito que não terá problemas com converter o código para sua realidade.

**Uma Classe Para o objeto de exemplo:**

```
 public class Cadastro
 {
    public byte[] Foto { get; set; }
 }
```

**Uma Classe onde se teria a comunicação com o banco:**

```
public class CadastroRepositorio
{
    public List<Cadastro> Select()
    {
        List<Cadastro> retorno = new List<Cadastro>();
        string sql = @"Select foto from tabela where id = 1;";
        using (OdbcConnection conexao = new OdbcConnection("string de conexao"))
        {
            conexao.Open();
            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, conexao))
            {
                using (OdbcDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    Cadastro obj;
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        obj = new Cadastro();
                        obj.Foto = new byte[0];
                        obj.Foto = (dr[0].ToString().Length != 0 ? (byte[])dr[0] : obj.Foto);
                        //obj.Foto = (dr["foto"].ToString().Length != 0 ? (byte[])dr["foto"] : obj.Foto); 
                        retorno.Add(obj);
                    }

                    dr.Close();
                }
            }
            conexao.Close();
        }
        return retorno;
    }

    public int Insert(Cadastro obj)
    {
        int r = 0;
        string sql = @"insert into tabela (foto) value (?);";
        using (OdbcConnection conexao = new OdbcConnection("string de conexao"))
        {
            conexao.Open();
            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, conexao))
            {
                OdbcParameter param = new OdbcParameter("foto", OdbcType.Binary);
                param.Value = (obj.Foto == null ? null : ( obj.Foto.Length == 0 ? null : obj.Foto));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                r = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            conexao.Close();
        }
        return r;
    }

    public int Update(Cadastro obj)
    {
        int r = 0;
        string sql = @"update tabela set foto = ? where id = 1;";
        using (OdbcConnection conexao = new OdbcConnection("string de conexao"))
        {
            conexao.Open();
            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, conexao))
            {
                OdbcParameter param = new OdbcParameter("foto", OdbcType.Binary);
                param.Value = (obj.Foto == null ? null : (obj.Foto.Length == 0 ? null : obj.Foto));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                r = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            conexao.Close();
        }
        return r;
    }
}
```

Por fim, caso necessário pode-se converter o `byte[]` para uma `Image` utilizando a seguinte função: (Esta não é de minha autoria)

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converte um array de bytes em um objeto System.Drawing.Image
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pic">byte[]</param>
    /// <returns>System.Drawing.Image</returns>
    public static Image ConvertByteToImage(byte[] pic)
    {
        if (pic != null)
        {
            try
            {
                MemoryStream ImageDataStream = new MemoryStream();
                ImageDataStream.Write(pic, 0, pic.Length);
                ImageDataStream.Position = 0;
                pic = System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.Default, pic);
                System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ImageDataStream);
                return img;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }

        }
        else return null;
    }
```

E a função reversa, para converter uma imagem para byte[]:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Converte um objeto System.Drawing.Image em um array de bytes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="foto">System.Drawing.Image</param>
    /// <returns>byte[]</returns>
    public static byte[] ConvertImageToByte(System.Drawing.Image foto)
    {
        if (foto == null)
            return null;
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(foto);
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        bmp.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
        stream.Flush();
        byte[] pic = stream.ToArray();
        return pic;
    }
```

> Agora a parte do backup e restore:

Para fazer o backup, utilizo o seguinte comando:

```
C:\Progra~2\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin\pg_dump -h [host] -p 5432 -U postgres --inserts -c -f D:\PostgreSQL\Backups\[arquivo de backup].dump [nome database]
```

Para fazer o restore, utilizo o seguinte comando:

```
C:\Progra~2\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin\psql -U postgres -d [nome database] -f D:\PostgreSQL\Backups\[arquivo de backup].dump
```

Funciona perfeitamente, não só para imagens como também para arquivos (.doc, .zip, .exe, etc). Espero ter ajudado.

Obs.: Trabalho em ambiente `Windows`

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, eu utilizo C# WPF, precisei fazer algumas modificações mas deu certo com base no que você me passou aqui, porém ao salvar no banco de dados ocorre um problema pois minha biblioteca é diferente da sua e não conta com a OdbcType.Binary, caso consiga me ajudar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/236577/problema-ao-inserir-bytea-no-postgresql

Comment: =] feliz em ajudar. Sobre o outro problema, já respondi o que acredito ser. vlw

Comment: Depois que você monta a string para o backup ou restore como você executa ela ?

Comment: Por exemplo, eu tenho um software e instalado ele em clientes diferentes, e nem sempre o meu postgreSQL fica com o mesmo caminho, você deixa sempre estático ou faz algo para o sistema encontre o local onde está o banco?

Comment: Particularmente, tenho isso em arquivo de lotes, os famosos `.bat` que executam pelo agendador de tarefas do windows. Por dentro da aplicação você pode executar pela classe `system.diagnostics.process.start()`

Comment: Quando você usa Progra~2 com isso é possivel referenciar os dois arquivos de programas?

Comment: não... isso é o padrão de nomes do windows, quando utiliza-se a linha de comando. Como há duas pastas, `Program Files` e `Program Files (x86)` a primeira, fica como `Progra~1` e a segunda como `Progra~2`. Se houvesse uma terceira pasta, ficaria como `Progra~3`. Para ver esses nomes, digite `dir /x` na linha de comando

Comment: Você poderia me ajudar a realizar o restore? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/237419/problemas-ao-restaurar-uma-base-de-dados-em-postgresql-com-c