# Problema ao Inserir Bytea no postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, byte

Fiz esse update para atualizar uma coluna na minha tabela empresa, a minha coluna no banco de dados é do tipo `bytea` e estou salvando uma imagem como byte[] ... na minha classe empresa, tenho a variavel Foto que é do tipo `Byte [] Foto`

```
 public int Update(clsEmpresa E)
  {
     int r = 0;
     string sql = @"update empresa set emp_figura = ?;";

 string connString = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};",
 clsConfigBanco.SERVERNAME, clsConfigBanco.PORT, clsConfigBanco.USERNAME, clsConfigBanco.PASSWORD, clsConfigBanco.DATABASENAME);

 using (NpgsqlConnection conexao = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
 {
     conexao.Open();
     using (NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conexao))
     {
        NpgsqlParameter param = new NpgsqlParameter("emp_figura", 
        NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Bytea); 
        param.Value = (E.Foto == null ? null : (E.Foto.Length == 0 ? null : E.Foto));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
        r = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
     conexao.Close();
 }

     return r;
}
```

Quando executo esse método ocorre o seguinte erro
`ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near ";"` quando faço o `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery;`

Será que o erro seria referente a utilizando do `NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Bytea` relacionado ao tipo do meu parâmetro? Qual seria a maneira correta para salvar esse Array de byte no banco?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

troque

`"update empresa set emp_figura = ?;"`

por

`"update empresa set emp_figura = :emp_figura;"`

eu colocaria um `where` aí com a chave primária da empresa também. Mesmo que só tenha uma, acredito que seja melhor.

o `?` é utilizado quando está usando um driver ODBC, pelo menos no `postgresql`. Já com o `Npgsql`, você nomeia o parâmetro na query, com o prefixo `:`

Comment: Eu consigo utilizar o ODBC para qualquer banco de dados? é como se fosse uma biblioteca genérica? ou não?

Comment: ODBC é um driver de conexão... dentro do C# você vai utilizar o namespace `System.Data.ODBC` para qualquer banco, porém, no computador é necessário instalar o driver do banco específico e a sintaxe das querys pode variar conforme o banco de dados também. Acredito que o recomendável seja utilizar a biblioteca específica para cada banco, ODBC você pode perder um pouco de desempenho, e já tive problemas com processamentos muito longos. Ainda tenho alguns códigos assim mas pretendo passar tudo para Npgsql =]