# Problemas ao restaurar uma base de dados em PostgreSQL com C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

```
private void btnRestore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (clsB.ConectaBanco())
    {
        //Executo a seguinte função para limpar a base de dados, para poder dar o restore.
        clsB.ExecutarSQL("drop schema public cascade; create schema public;");

        //E executo o seguinte processo
        string Comando = CaminhoPg + @"psql -U postgres -d restore2 -f C:\Users\bruhh\Desktop\Backup\back.backup";

        Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        p.StartInfo.FileName = CaminhoPg + @"psql" ;
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-U postgres -d restore2 -f C:\Users\bruhh\Desktop\Backup\back.backup";

        p.Start();

        p.WaitForExit();
        p.Close();

        MessageBox.Show(Comando);
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Ocorreu um erro ao carregar as configurações do banco de dados! \nvá em Configurações\\Banco De Dados");
}
```

O Resultado da váriavel comando é

```
C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.4\\bin\\psql -U postgres -d restore2 -f C:\\Users\\bruhh\\Desktop\\Backup\\back.backup
```

O processo até executa mas em todas as linhas aparece "comando invalido". O que seria necessário para fazer esse código funcionar?

Como fica o processo quando é executado
[image: Processo executado]

[EDIT] Método utilizado para realizar o Backup

```
public string BackupDatabase(string CaminhoNome)
{
    string server = clsConfigBanco.SERVERNAME;
    string port = clsConfigBanco.PORT;
    string user = clsConfigBanco.USERNAME;
    string password = clsConfigBanco.PASSWORD;
    string dbname = clsConfigBanco.DATABASENAME;
    string backupCommandDir = @"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin";
    try
    {
       Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PGPASSWORD", password);

       string backupFile = CaminhoNome;
       string BackupString = "-ibv -Z3 -f \"" + backupFile + "\" " +
                "-Fc -h " + server + " -U " + user + " -p " + port + " " + dbname;

       Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
       p.StartInfo.FileName = CaminhoPg + "\\pg_dump.exe";
       p.StartInfo.Arguments = BackupString;

       p.Start();

       p.WaitForExit();
       p.Close();

       return backupFile;
   }
   catch
   {
      return "";
    }


 }
```

Comment: mostra como está seu dump, pelo menos o início dele

Comment: O que seria esse dump?

Comment: Oi? O arquivo gerado pelo 'pg_dump' que seria seu backup... No seu caso, "back.backup"

Comment: Está pegando alguns valores null e lixo. bem estranho, aparentemente está com problema esse arquivo back.backup. mas acho que ele é o problema, porque pelo restore do pg ele dá certo, segue o link para download do arquivo https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArOnQw2yo1TchI963AaYsahjuPMaSg

Comment: tem algo de errado com esse dump seu... rs como está fazendo ele ?

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta com o método para a realização do backup

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que esteja usando o `Process.Start` de forma errada. Veja o exemplo:

```
static void LaunchCommandLineApp()
{
    // For the example.
    const string exe = "C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.4\\bin\\psql";
    const string arg = "-U postgres -d restore2 -f C:\\Users\\bruhh\\Desktop\\Backup\\back.backup";

    // Use ProcessStartInfo class.
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = exe;
    startInfo.Arguments = arg;

    try
    {
        // Start the process with the info we specified.
        // Call WaitForExit and then the using-statement will close.
        using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
            exeProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        // Log error.
    }
}
```

retirei o exemplo deste site: https://www.dotnetperls.com/process

fora isso, aparentemente não encontrei nada de errado. Se possível, coloque mais informações, de como está o dump e as mensagens de erro que aparecem.

Comment: Atualiza com uma imagem do processo, olhe como ocorre quando ele é executado, Pensei que o erro era referente ao backup (deveria estar com problemas) porém quando eu uso ele pelo postgre ele funciona normalmente